# PHP. How to repeat and modify HTML code for array elements?

Tags: php

I have `$array=array("nothing","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");` and a piece of code as a template:

```
$var=<<<EOF

$array[0]
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li>$array[1]</li>
    <li>$array[2]</li>
    <li>$array[3]</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>

EOF;
```

I want dynamically repeat and modify this HTML code while there are array elements. I mean this result:

```
$var=<<<EOF

$array[0]
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li>$array[1]</li>
    <li>$array[2]</li>
    <li>$array[3]</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li>$array[4]</li>
    <li>$array[5]</li>
    <li>$array[6]</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li>$array[7]</li>
    <li>$array[8]</li>
    <li>$array[9]</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li>$array[10]</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>

EOF;
```

Comment: Check out the manual entry on foreach loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Nadav's answer and making it better:

```
<?php
$array = array(0);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); ): ?>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $array[$i++] ?></li> // i == 1, 4, 7, ....
    <li><?php echo $array[$i++] ?></li> // i == 2, 5, 8, ....
    <li><?php echo $array[$i++] ?></li> // i == 3, 6, 9, ....
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

---

But then the above **will fail** if 2,3 dont exist or 5,6 don't exist, etc.

## Update:

This code will work correctly:

```
<?php

$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11, 22);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($array);): ?>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <?php for($j = 0; $j < 3 && $i + $j < count($array); ++$j):?>
    <li><?php echo $array[$j + $i] ?></li>
    <?php endfor; $i += $j;?> 
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/LFGMkd1G

Comment: @YNT I have the 2nd part working. I am updating and putting DEMO

Comment: @YNT I updated my answer with a working answer and demo. Please let me know if you need a code explanation.

Comment: It works and this is the best explanation. This code is very complicated for me; however, I can copy-past :-).

Comment: @YNT break it down, bit by bit, I am sure you will get it eventually :-)

Comment: I have to because it is very interesting to learn programming.

Comment: @YNT my old code did not work correctly. see my update. use that :-)

Comment: @YNT and **now** you should be all good :-) sorry for the old code, it was **BAD**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array[0];

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i + 3) {
?>
<div>
  <!-- something else -->
  <ul>
    <li><? $array[$i + 1] ?></li>
    <li><? $array[$i + 2] ?></li>
    <li><? $array[$i + 3] ?></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- something else -->
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The loop you wanted isn't standard, so can only hope it works for you.

Basically it start with `$i = 0`, and prints `$i + 1`(= 1), (=2), (=3), next round `$i` equals 3 (`$i + 3`), and prints `$i + 1`(=3+1=4), (=5) , (=6), and so on, until the array reaches its end.

Comment: Note that with this code you will loose the last one or two elements if the number of elements in the array is not divisible by 3 (e.g. if you have 5 elements, you'll print only the first 3)

Comment: @Nadav Thanks for your answer, I'll try to apply this.